# Swift detect if beacon is out of range

Tags: android, iphone, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon

I have an iOS app which scans nearby Beacons using CoreBluetooth. 
But I have to detect if a beacon is out of range. I already did something like this in android:

```
 @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            if(expirationTime <= 0) {
                device.setLost(true);
                if(!BeaconScanCallback.getBeaconScanCallbackInstance(activity).isInBackground())
                activity.getListAdapter().removeDevice(device);
                DeviceManager.getInstance().removeDevice(device);

                if(getLocation() != null) {
                    Log.i("AUTOLOST", "Device lost: " + device.getDeviceName() +  "   " + getLocation().getLatitude());
                    activity.postDeviceLocation(device, getLocation().getLatitude(), getLocation().getLongitude(), BeaconStatus.BEACON_LOST, "Device lost");
                }
            } else {
                expirationTime -= 1;
                if(isAccepted()) {
                    handler.postDelayed(new AutoLost(device), expirationTimer);
                }
            }
        } finally {
        }

    }
```

In android a beacon gets scanned even though it was already scanned once. So I was able to set a timeout method which will autmatically remove it from an array as soon as it is not scanned in a certain time (1 minute).

So here is my question: 
In Swift I am not able to scan a beacon twice if it was already scanned once, so i don't think that this method will work again. Is there any possibility to check if a beacon is out of range and not scannable any more (Beacon lost)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually can get multiple callbacks from CoreBluetooth on iOS to the `func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber)` delegate method, **if** you specify the `CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey` when you start scanning.  Like this:

```
centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: uuids, 
        options: [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey: true] )
```

It is worth noting, however, that this only allows you to get multiple callbacks for the same advertisement when the app is in the foreground.  In the background, this option is ignored.

Using the above it is possible to use a timestamp as you do in Android to see when the beacon has not been seen in awhile and determine that it is no longer in range.

Comment: I tried and this works. With this I can finally adapt the solution I had in android. Thank you! Is there any native support for beacon-loss-detection?

Comment: Well, native beacon support on iOS is all for iBeacon using CoreLocation.  And, yes, it supports a `didExit(region: region)` callback when beacons matching an identifier pattern are no longer seen. If you are talking CoreBluetooth, however, I am not aware of any native APIs that will tell you when a certain `CBPeripheral` has not been detected in a certain amount of time.  My presumption is that you are not using iBeacon, because if you were you would not be able to detect them with CoreBluetooth anyway since Apple blocks reading their advertisements with these APIs.